# Python Persistent TCP client

Tags: python, tcp, connection, telnet, persistent

I need to connect to my server(not http) with a persistent connection, to speed up some things. Could I have an example of how to do this?

Answer (score 2):

You can use [socket](http://docs.python.org/library/socket.html) library and there are many examples in documentation.

```
>>> from socket import socket
>>> sock = socket()
>>> sock.connect(("173.194.32.41", 80))
>>> sock.send("Some stuff\r\n\r\n")
14
>>> sock.recv(12)
'HTTP/1.0 400'
```

There is also [telnetlib](http://docs.python.org/library/telnetlib.html) in python standard library.

Comment: But I want to send multiple strings and receive multiple strings with one connection?

Comment: Is there a way to check whether the server is waiting to send or receive?